# regression equation

Tags: regression

calculating intercept a= 1.43  with slope b=1.7, what would the regression equation look like with no controlled variables? I have searched and only get partial answers and do not understand how to put it all together.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "no controlled variables"? Do you mean "no x variables" (in which case what do you mean by the slope?) or do you mean "there is an x variable, but I do not know its value so can only write it symbolically as 'x'" or are you referring to different variables altogether?

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 0):

$\bar{y}=1.43+1.7*x$, that is what you would get.

Comment: Hmm.  I would have written Y' = 1.43 + 1.7X.  The inclusion of the error term feels like we are mixing the prediction equation (hence Y' rather than Y) and the model.

Comment: Edited to take your point into account.